# Decrease vertical thicknes of bars in Likert Chart R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I making graph in R. I amusing likert chart. I want to decrease vertical thickness of bars. Does anyone have any idea. How to do that. Following is my script.

```
require(likert)
require(HH)
Q2 <- c(11.76, 11.76, 17.65, 47.06, 11.76)
Q3 <- c(0, 17.65, 23.53, 23.53, 35.29)
Q4 <- c(5.88, 35.29, 23.53, 29.41, 5.88)
Q  <- data.frame(Q2, Q3, Q4)
Q  <- t(Q)
PCWP <- c("#A8C2C0", "#C9E9E6", "#AAFFBB","#D0E39A", "#A3B37B")
colnames(Q) <- c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", 
                 "Agree", "Strongly Agree")
items <- list(c("Q2", "Q3", "Q4"))

likert(
       Q, col=PCWP, main="projects",
       xlab="Percentage", ylab="Question",
       par.settings= list(
                          layout.widths=list(axis.right=1, axis.key.padding=0,
                          ylab.right=1, right.padding=1)
                         )
      )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?likert` (from `HH`).  Use the `box.ratio` argument:

```
likert(
       Q, col=PCWP, main="projects",
       xlab="Percentage", ylab="Question", box.ratio=0.5,
       par.settings= list(
                          layout.widths=list(axis.right=1, axis.key.padding=0,
                          ylab.right=1, right.padding=1)
                         )
      )
```

Comment: I can't find anything about `box.ratio` in `?likert` and neither this code nor the OP's works for me. Am I losing my mind?

Comment: @thelatemail Did you do `require(HH)`? See: [http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/HH/docs/likert](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/HH/docs/likert)

Comment: Well, that's just plain confusing. When I do `?likert` I get `?likert::likert` not `?HH::likert` regardless of both being loaded.

Comment: @thelatemail Interesting.  I get the option to choose, and I just assumed everyone else would too.